# How to write data into a .SYLK File Or Convert SLK File data

Tags: java, export-to-excel, slk

I have a code that contains a function taking columns and rows and exporting it to an SLK file. It uses a specific style-sheet ( for example dates are shown in a certain way, and prices in another one). However, the file's representation has been written using a long string and is undocumented. I need to write the same function using java and wanted to know if there is a better way for re-writing this code , for instance using apache HSSFWorkbook class.

However , i don't know what my current string representation means.

So my questions are:

1. Is there other open source classes that i can use writing this code
2. Is there any site that can show me what each of this string represents ( which style ), so i can initilize the write one using HSSFWorkbook  class

Thanks Ido

my current function starts like this and doesn't look good ( it's in javascript and I need to re-write it in java):

```
function exportToSlk(columns, rows,filename, $a) {
    var formatMaps = {
        "$#,###.##":"F;P34;F$2G;",
        "$#0.00":"F;P34;F$2G;",
        "$#0.000" : "F;P34;F$2G;",
        "#,###":"F;P39;FI0G;",
        "%#0.00":"F;P14;F%2G;",
        "date": "F;P19;FG0G;"
    };
    var header =   'ID;PWXL;N;E\nO;L\nP;PGeneral\nP;P0\nP;P0.00\nP;P#,##0\nP;P#,##0.00\nP;P#,##0_);;\\(#,##0\\)\nP;P#,##0_);;[Red]\\(#,##0\\)\nP;P#,##0.00_);;\\(#,##0.00\\)\nP;P#,##0.00_);;[Red]\\(#,##0.00\\)\nP;P"$"#,##0_);;\\("$"#,##0\\)\nP;P"$"#,##0_);;[Red]\\("$"#,##0\\)\nP;P"$"#,##0.00_);;\\("$"#,##0.00\\)\nP;P"$"#,##0.00_);;[Red]\\("$"#,##0.00\\)\nP;P0%\nP;P0.00%\nP;P0.00E+00\nP;P##0.0E+0\nP;P#\\ ?/?\nP;P#\\ ??/??\nP;Pm/d/yyyy\nP;Pd\\-mmm\\-yy\nP;Pd\\-mmm\nP;Pmmm\\-yy\nP;Ph:mm\\ AM/PM\nP;Ph:mm:ss\\ AM/PM\nP;Ph:mm\nP;Ph:mm:ss\nP;Pm/d/yyyy\\ h:mm\nP;Pmm:ss\nP;Pmm:ss.0\nP;P@\nP;P[h]:mm:ss\nP;P_("$"* #,##0_);;_("$"* \\(#,##0\\);;_("$"* "-"_);;_(@_)\nP;P_(* #,##0_);;_(* \\(#,##0\\);;_(* "-"_);;_(@_)\nP;P_("$"* #,##0.00_);;_("$"* \\(#,##0.00\\);;_("$"* "-"??_);;_(@_)\nP;P_(* #,##0.00_);;_(* \\(#,##0.00\\);;_(* "-"??_);;_(@_)\nP;P_(* #,##0.000_);;_(* \\(#,##0.000\\);;_(* "-"??_);;_(@_)\nP;P_(* #,##0.0000_);;_(* \\(#,##0.0000\\);;_(* "-"??_);;_(@_)\nP;P_(* #,##0.0_);;_(* \\(#,##0.0\\);;_(* "-"??_);;_(@_)\nP;P_(* #,##0_);;_(* \\(#,##0\\);;_(* "-"??_);;_(@_)\nP;Pmmm\\-yyyy\nP;FCalibri;M220;L9\nP;FCalibri;M220;L9\nP;FCalibri;M220;L9\nP;FCalibri;M220;L9\nP;ECalibri;M220;L9\nP;ECambria;M360;SB;L57\nP;ECalibri;M300;SB;L57\nP;ECalibri;M260;SB;L57\nP;ECalibri;M220;SB;L57\nP;ECalibri;M220;L18\nP;ECalibri;M220;L21\nP;ECalibri;M220;L61\nP;ECalibri;M220;L63\nP;ECalibri;M220;SB;L64\nP;ECalibri;M220;SB;L53\nP;ECalibri;M220;L53\nP;ECalibri;M220;SB;L10\nP;ECalibri;M220;L11\nP;ECalibri;M220;SI;L24\nP;ECalibri;M220;SB;L9\nP;ECalibri;M220;L10\nP;ECalibri;M220;L9\nP;ECambria;M360;SB;L57\nP;ECalibri;M300;SB;L57\nP;ECalibri;M260;SB;L57\nP;ECalibri;M220;SB;L57\nP;ECalibri;M220;L18\nP;ECalibri;M220;L21\nP;ECalibri;M220;L61\nP;ECalibri;M220;L63\nP;ECalibri;M220;SB;L64\nP;ECalibri;M220;SB;L53\nP;ECalibri;M220;L53\nP;ECalibri;M220;SB;L10\nP;ECalibri;M220;L11\nP;ECalibri;M220;SI;L24\nP;ECalibri;M220;SB;L9\nP;ECalibri;M220;L10\nF;P0;DG0G8;M300\n';

    var exported = header;
    //now handle col width
    for(var i=1; i<=columns.length; i++) {
        exported += "F;W"+i+" "+i+" 15\n";
    }
    ...
}
```